# Compiling C source files written for POSIX system on Windows

Tags: c, linux, windows, bash, posix

To compile a string matching tool [SMART](https://github.com/smart-tool/smart/releases) **in windows command**, implemented in `C` programming language, the instruction was (in  the [the instruction set](https://www.dmi.unict.it/faro/smart/howto.php), after extracting the zip files):

> how to compile smart source code:
> **makefile is the bash file** used for compiling the C source files of the tool. Run the command `./makefile` in order to compile the smart
> tool.  The code of each string matching algorithm is compiled an
> tested separately.

The `makefile` contains the follwoing code:

```
#!/bin/bash
./logo
echo "  Compiling smart.c..................................[OK]"
gcc source/smart.c -O3 -msse2 -o smart -lm
echo "  Compiling show.c...................................[OK]"
gcc source/show.c -O3 -msse2 -o show
echo "  Compiling selectAlgo.c.............................[OK]"
gcc source/selectAlgo.c -O3 -o select
echo "  Compiling test.c...................................[OK]"
gcc source/test.c -O3 -o test
echo "  Compiling all string matching algorithms..........."
gcc source/compilesm.c -o compilesm
./compilesm
echo " "
echo " "
```

**It appears to be written to work on a POSIX system, such as GNU/Linux or macOS. I want to compile it on Windows.** So, I did the following:

1. Installed `Git-2.37.1-64-bit.exe` and opened `Git Bash`
2. Executed command: `cd C:/Users/DIMITRI/Downloads/smart-13.03`
3. Executed command: `./makefile`
   But I got the following error:

   source/smart.c:44:10: fatal error: sys/ipc.h: No such file or directory

The problem is that I am trying to use the Linux API on Windows. This error will occur for `#include <sys/shm.h>` also.

Is it possible to overcome this missing header-file problem (these files can not be included in Windows) by using different compiler (I have, x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project, 8.1.0) or installing another system on Windows (without installing Linux or other complicated, heavy system)?

Generally, is there a way to compile C source files written for POSIX system on Windows?

Thanks.

EDIT:

1. According to one suggestion of one member, I have tried Cygwin, got the same error.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/).

Comment: Windows Subsystem for Linux if you run windows 10+

Comment: @Gerhardh this is developed by Simone Faro, Associate Professor of Computer Science, University of Catania, this is his page: https://www.dmi.unict.it/faro/   for the detail of the tool, see: https://smart-tool.github.io/smart/

Comment: @PhilMasteG just did it, same error, why did you think that would be different?

Comment: You could also use MSYS2 which is similar to Cygwin. Both MSYS2 and Cygwin use a special run-time DLL that emulates POSIX facilities using native Windows equivalents.

Comment: @IanAbbott I have tried Cygwin just now, got the same error, why do you think MSYS2  would be different than Git, Cygwin?

Comment: @Michael You may need to install some devel packages in Cygwin or MSYS2. In MSYS2, /usr/include/sys/ipc.h is provided by the `msys2-runtime-devel` package (`pacman -S msys2-runtime-devel`). (I'm not sure what you need in Cygwin.)

Comment: @IanAbbott okay, then I am to try MSYS2, but would `MSYS2` resolve issue related to `#include <sys/shm.h>` too?

Comment: `/usr/include/sys/shm.h` is provided by the same MSYS2 package.

Comment: @IanAbbott worse result: `Compiling smart.c..................................[OK]
./makefile: line 4: gcc: command not found
        Compiling show.c...................................[OK]
./makefile: line 6: gcc: command not found
        Compiling selectAlgo.c.............................[OK]
./makefile: line 8: gcc: command not found
        Compiling test.c...................................[OK]
./makefile: line 10: gcc: command not found
        Compiling all string matching algorithms...........
./makefile: line 12: gcc: command not found

`

Comment: `Compiling file ac.c............[ERROR]
        Compiling file ag.c............[ERROR]
        Compiling file akc.c...........[ERROR]
        Compiling file aoso2.c.........[ERROR]`

......

Comment: `pacman -S gcc`, and also, `pacman -S base-devel`.

Comment: Why don't you ask the author of the package these questions?

Comment: @IanAbbott it works! Post your answer (I will accept and vote) as following: pacman -S base-devel
// after above, do the below:
pacman -S gcc
//then go to 
cd C:/Users/DIMITRI/Downloads/smart-13.03
./makefile //compiling, for the first time

Comment: @IanAbbott but now I am getting `shmget: Function not implemented` when I run `./smart -text englishTexts`, what kind of package do I need for that?

Comment: In Cygwin, `shmget` *is* implemented, but “only available when cygserver is running” (https://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/std-notes.html). Not sure of MSYS, though.

Comment: @numzero yes I did the search on SO too and found the result, still searching, but haven't found anything....only the expert can figure out such issue... solutions are simple, but one has to know..

Comment: Sorry it seems MSYS2 only implement the functions enough to generate an ENOSYS error.