# Package for MSYS2 to resolve shmget Error

Tags: c, linux, bash, memory, msys2

I have compiled a string matching tool [SMART](https://github.com/smart-tool/smart/releases) **in windows** using `MSYS2`, the tool is implemented in `C` programming language. The instruction was (in  the [the instruction set](https://www.dmi.unict.it/faro/smart/howto.php)):

> **makefile is the bash file** used for compiling the C source files of the tool. Run the command `./makefile` in order to compile the smart
> tool.  The code of each string matching algorithm is compiled an
> tested separately.

The problem now is, each algorithm is compiled properly but tested unsuccessfully.

Also, when the following command is given to execute (see [how to run experimental tests](https://www.dmi.unict.it/faro/smart/howto.php)):

```
./smart -text englishTexts
```

I get the following error:

```
shmget: Function not implemented
```

I doubt both issues are related/due to the failure of `managing shared memory`, note that author created the system  on a POSIX system (whereas I am trying to run this  on a Windows system). Author wrote about the `Manage shared memory on LINUX`:

> In order to configure shared memory on linux you have to login as
> root, then edit the file

`/etc/sysctl.conf.`

> The kernel.shmax parameter defines the maximum size in bytes for a
> shared memory segment. Determine the value of kernel.shmax by
> performing the following:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
33554432
```

> The kernel.shmall parameter sets the total amount of shared memory in
> pages that can be used at one time on the system. Set the value of
> both of these parameters to the amount physical memory on the machine.
> As in the previous case you can determine the value of kernel.shmax by
> performing the following:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmall
2097152
```

> Set the values of kernel.shmax and kernel.shmall, as follows:

```
echo MemSize > /proc/sys/shmmax
echo MemSize > /proc/sys/shmall
```

> where MemSize is the number of bytes. For example, to set both values
> to 2GB, use the following:

```
echo 2147483648 > /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
echo 2147483648 > /proc/sys/kernel/shmall
```

> Then reboot the machine using. Shared memory can be viewed with the
> ipcs command and you can delete shared memory segments with the ipcrm
> command.

But there is nothing specific about `Windows` (though there is a paragraph for "Manage shared memory on WINDOWS VISTA").

At this point I ask your help, to inform me whether there is a package for MSYS2 to solve `shmget` error mentioned above? Or there are other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72993806/compiling-c-source-files-written-for-posix-system-on-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think you're out of luck with msys2. msys2 [takes out cygserver](https://www.msys2.org/wiki/How-does-MSYS2-differ-from-Cygwin/) from cygwin, which is [required for shared memory](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using-shared-memory.html).

Comment: I have very little knowledge, so would you kindly inform me the solution explicitly, please?

Comment: Only solution I can think of is to stop using msys2 and move to cygwin instead, where this functionality is available.